# C# - No overload for method (takes 0 arguments)

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, overloading

I have this little piece of code inside a project:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2_Click();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = 0;
}
```

Now, I want to call the button2_Click method, but I cannot because I have to pass arguments.

The problem is, I don't know what arguments to pass when calling the method.

What should I pass?

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2_Click(this.button2,EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = 0;
}
```

just treat it as normal parameter. but it's not recommand like it. the best Practice is Extract the body of button2_Click and call the Extract method.the button2_Click should alway be trigger by user Interface.for example :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   method();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    method();
}   
public void method(){
  //x=0 or other
  ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I just used:

```
button2_Click(sender, e)
```

and it worked.

Comment: not cool you get a text box as sender in a button click event. That is not what anybody would expect. better use button.PerformClick()